# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function error in drupal 6 after creating a module

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

[image]I am working on a Drupal 6 site although I am a newbie to Drupal and php. I was creating a module based on the code for an existing module and I am getting a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ...return_zip_codes() in ..../modules/cck/content.module(1694) : eval()'d code on line 2" error. I lost all access to the drupal site via the web interface when this error occurred.  I have since deleted the offending module and tried clearing all the cac[image]hes and running cron using Drush and clearing the cache tables using mysql commandline but the error still persisted. Running drush cron and drush cc all was also "aborting" due to the error. I am not getting much when I google the error. I have attached a screen shot of the original error I am getting.

I commented out a line on the stack trace and I managed to get the site back up, but I get another error when I click a link to register a new member. Also commenting out that line has caused some forms to display incorrectly together with some elements of the landing page.

I attached the printscreens of the errors I get as well as some of the code I edited. Let me know if there is more information and code that you need me to supply.

Thank you

The codewith the line I commented out in content.module file on line 1694

```
enter code here

  $allowed_values[$cid] = array();
if (isset($field['allowed_values_php'])) {
ob_start();
//    $result = eval($field['allowed_values_php']);
if (is_array($result)) {
  if ($flatten) {
    $result = content_array_flatten($result);
  }
  $allowed_values[$cid] = $result;
}
ob_end_clean();
}
```

The code in the module I created which resulted in the error:

```
enter code here

    'widget_active' => '1',
'type' => 'text',
'required' => '1',
'multiple' => '0',
'module' => 'text',
'active' => '1',
'text_processing' => 0,
'max_length' => '',
'allowed_values' => '',
'allowed_values_php' => 'module_load_include(\'inc\', \'online_![enter image      description here][3]mem_apps\', \'/includes/online_mem_apps.zip_codes\');
return online_mem_apps_return_zip_codes(TRUE);',
'field_permissions' => array(
  'create' => 0,
  'edit' => 0,
  'edit own' => 0,
  'view' => 0,
  'view own' => 0,
),
```